# Enabling Devtools extension for pages from a particular domain?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to add new tabs/panel to Dev Tools i.e a devtool extension. But want to add only when the main page/inspected window opened is of specific domain. Any way I can achieve this?

Right now the following adds tab in Dev Tools for every page I visit. The `"permissions"` part of the manifest.json is not honored?

Would like to know if I can limit the devtool extension to limited pages, or if I create a devtool extension it's going to be available for all pages?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Devtools extension",
  "description": "XYZ",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "https://*.google.com/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "vf.jpg",
    "default_title": "rc"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },    
  "devtools_page" : "devtools.html"
}`
```

**devtools.js included in devtools.html**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
    "New Tab", 
    "icon.png", 
    "dummy.html",
    function() {
      console.log("tab added");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Little late but it might help others, I did this in my devtools.js

```
var expr = '/^www.mydomain.com/.test(document.location.host)';
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(expr, cb);

function cb(data, isException) {
  if (!isException && data === true) {
      chrome.devtools.panels.create(
        'New Tab',
        null, // No icon path
        'dummy.html',
        null // no callback needed
      );
    }
}
```